# Looking for script to evaluate datatype usage

Tags: datatypes

I'm using SQL Server 2016.

I'm trying to find a script that could be run against all tables to evaluate the datatype of each column. The idea would be to get feedback on whether performance could be improved if the column was switched to different datatype. Also, it could find situations in which a large datatype is being used unnecessarily and a smaller one could be set based on the actual data in the column.

I'd figure that I'd ask here, as I'm not finding anything with a quick google search. Please let me know if there is a blog post or script that someone has written already.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will find such scripts in a ready to use state. It is too business oriented task than a technical one.

Look first of all at string fields. If they contain data like numbers or dates - consider them changing to numeric and date types.
If you suspect that this is a case, you can do something like

```
select cast( text_field as int ) from table
```

If there is indeed just numbers in the field, this would work fine. If some record has a text which is not convertable to an integer - the query will fail. You would have to find this record and check is it a mistake or an actual reason why this field was made a text one instead of integer.

Same approach to `date` and `datetime` fields.

If you have a large string field, you can run a query like

```
select max(length(string_field)) from table
```

Which would give you length of the longest actual string. But reducing the size of it will not really affect performance. It can affect how wide the record is if you go from `char(255)` to `char(25)`, but not so for `varchar`. And if previously you had two records per page and now you have three - this can increase I/O performance. But if number of records per page does not change from your field reductions - no performance gains at all.

But this whole exercise will give you very little gain, even if some. Much better would be to tune queries, check which indexes to create, how to get rid of subqueries, or where you do unneeded joins.

Comment: `TRY_CAST` and checking for null would make more sense.